# establish a connection with new signalr library

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, asp.net-core-signalr

I used the following code to connect to a asp.net core signalR server. But I could not manage to have a connection. Is there something I am doing wrong? 
I am getting this error,

> Error: The "promise" option must be a Promise

```
var hubUrl = "http://localhost:52273/logNotifierHub";
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection(hubUrl );
var hub = connection.invoke("LogNotifierHub");
var hubStart = connection.start({ jsonp: true });

connection.on("streamStarted", function () {
    startStreaming();
});
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "signalr",
    schema: {},
    transport: {
        signalr: {
            promise: hubStart,
            hub: hub,
            server: {read: "read"},
            client: {read: "read"}
        }
    }
});
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    height: 850,
    columns: [],                    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the SignalR promise object has changed, but you can solve this problem by adjusting the kendo plugin.

**kendo.data.signalr.js**

```
//if (typeof promise.done != 'function' || typeof promise.fail != 'function')
if (typeof promise.then != 'function')

...

//this.promise.done(function () {
//    hub.invoke.apply(hub, args).done(options.success).fail(options.error);
//});
this.promise.then(function() {
    hub.invoke.apply(hub, args).then(options.success);
});
```

Comment: does this fix mean that I still can get the data from signalR and populate my grid?

Comment: Yes. I had the same problem and manipulated this file (but you will lose the .fail() callback. Neccessary? I don't know.). Now my ListView is working fine with .net core signalR. In my case I added the kendo javascript files separated and not as one bundle. Maybe you also have to include the files splitted, but with the manipulated kendo.data.signalr.js. Or you have to search for the code blocks in the bundled kendo.js and replace it there. Its maybe a bit complicated to do this in the minified file, so you should use the non minified version.

Comment: looking to find a solution for current asp.net core releases and after 2 weeks of try and error this is the only solution that actually worked for me! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core uses completely new SignalR version and it is still in alpha stage. That said, it is not supported with the Kendo components.